# Delphi screen dimensions differ on two apps on same machine...how to resolve?

Tags: delphi-xe, tform

I have two applications that use some of the same forms. I noticed that these forms were displaying differently when I ran the applications. I put this code at the top of the project source:

```
var f: TextFile;
s: String;

{$R *.res}

begin

s := TPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExeName);
AssignFile(f, s + '-screen.txt');
Rewrite(f);
Writeln (f, s + '.Desktop TLHW: ' + IntToStr(screen.DesktopTop) + ', ' +
                                    IntToStr(screen.DesktopLeft) + ', ' +
                                    IntToStr(screen.DesktopHeight) + ', ' +
                                    IntToStr(screen.DesktopWidth));
CloseFile (f);
```

aDAM2-screen.txt showed: aDAM2.Desktop TLHW: 0, 0, 720, 1280

aDAM3-screen.txt showed: aDAM3.Desktop TLHW: 0, 0, 1080, 1920

I don't understand how this happens and am at a loss to resolve this, especially given that the TScreen properties are read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The likely explanation is that one program is subject to [DPI virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266.aspx), the other is not. The system has 150% font scaling specified.

The true resolution is 1920 by 1080, and `aDAM3` is reporting that, because it is not subject to DPI virtualization.

On the other hand `aDAM2` is subject to DPI virtualization, and so reports virtualized dimensions, which are the true dimensions divided by 1.5. That is 1280 by 720.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed to get going.